# Topological sort in Gremlin

Tags: graph-algorithm, gremlin, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort, tinkerpop3

Using the [Gremlin/TinkerPop](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/) query language, is there a way to compute the topological ordering of a directed acyclic graph?

For example, given a graph with the following edges

```
a -> b, a -> d, b -> c, c -> d, e -> c
```

I would like to obtain one of the following topological orderings: `a, b, e, c, d`, or `a, e, b, c, d`, or `e, a, b, c, d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, let's create your sample graph first:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV(id, "a").as("a").
  addV(id, "b").as("b").
  addV(id, "c").as("c").
  addV(id, "d").as("d").
  addV(id, "e").as("e").
  addE("link").from("a").to("b").
  addE("link").from("a").to("d").
  addE("link").from("b").to("c").
  addE("link").from("c").to("d").
  addE("link").from("e").to("c").iterate()
```

And this is [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm) implemented in Gremlin:

```
gremlin> g.V().not(__.inE()).store("x").
           repeat(outE().store("e").inV().not(inE().where(without("e"))).store("x")).
         cap("x")
==>[v[a],v[b],v[e],v[c],v[d]]
```

Comment: This does not provide the correct topological order, for example given the graph `a->b, b->c, c->d, a->d` the query returns `a, d, b, c`, but the correct answer is `a, b, c, d`.

As a side note, in order to execute this query without incurring in timeouts I had to move the `dedup()` inside the `repeat(...)`, because I have a huge DAG. I think it is semantically equivalent.

Comment: Updated. The sample graph and the expected result(s) helped a lot.

Comment: Thank you! It terminates even when the graph has loops, it is perfect.